# Falling back to original method in rspec-mocks

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, stub

Is it possible to tell RSpec::Mocks to stub a method for a set of values, *otherwise fallback to the original method*? For example:

```
File.stub(:exist?).with(/txt/).and_return(true)
File.exist? 'log.txt'    # returns true
File.exist? 'dev.log'    # <<< need to fallback to original File.exist? here
```

Currently the last call in the example above would raise a `MockExpectationError`, asking to provide a default value. Is it possible to instruct rspec-mocks to fallback to the original method?

Comment: This is related to rspec-mock's issue https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/23

Answer (score 5):

One could cache the original method, and call it explicitly:

```
original_method = File.method(:exist?)
File.stub(:exist?).with(anything()) { |*args| original_method.call(*args) }
File.stub(:exist?).with(/txt/).and_return(true)
```

However, this is too cumbersome. I hope to see a better answer.

For the sake of completeness, here is a generalization of the code above:

```
def stub_with_fallback(obj, method)
  original_method = obj.method(method)
  obj.stub(method).with(anything()) { |*args| original_method.call(*args) }
  return obj.stub(method)
end

# usage example:
stub_with_fallback(File, :exist?).with(/txt/).and_return(true)
```